# Error 1045(2800)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, zabbix, mysql-error-1045

I am currently trying to configure Zabbix on a Ubuntu. I downloaded the appliance version, as I am not familiar with Ubuntu and the appliance version, makes it easier to install. However, I am currently experiencing this error code:

> Error 1045(2800): Access denied for user 'root'@' localhost' (using
>   password: Yes)

Answer (score 0):

You should first connect without a password like this

```
mysql -u root
```

You can now reset the root password with this command

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_new_password') where USER='root';
```

Then flush the privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you do those steps, it should now work.

Source

https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Comment: Thank you, I will try that in a bit